# Passing swing screen to another Java application. Does swing update its screen when minimized?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, bufferedimage

my question is two folds:

Can you pass the screen of one Swing application to another Java program so the latter can act as a "viewer" of the former? Perhaps by passing a buffered image? Can you do this for an existing Java application without code change?  (if Swing allows getting the buffered image of any component by default)

A related question is let's say the above is possible and the Swing application is minimized but constantly changes its screen. Does Swing update its screen (perhaps buffer) so the previewer can show it appropriately? Does the OS matter in this case?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

all swing compoments are serializable, so you can store and send any view to other application

Answer (score 1):

1) You can create a BufferedImage of any Swing component. [Screen Image](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) does the work for you.

2) I've never tried it,but I don't see why your couldn't recreate the image as needed.